# Missing data partially importing filtered text file data through sql with excel vba

Tags: sql, excel, vba, text, filter

I would like to import a 30Mb text file into excel filtering just what I want.
I have tried with small files and I see that some columns with byte data shows problems. I see a black sell or wrong values.
I tried different provider for the connection but I loose always data.

text_2.txt:

```
946737293;98FECB80;FF;FF;0;0;0;0;FF;FF
946737293;98EAFFFE;0;EE;0;0;0;0;FF;FF
946737294;98FE0F82;65;6E;4F;0;0;0;FF;FF
946737295;8CFD0282;FF;FF;FF;FF;FF;FF;0;FD
946737295;9CE78280;FF;1;5;FF;FF;FF;FF;FF
946737295;9CE78280;C0;FF;0;0;0;0;FF;FF
946737296;8CFD0282;FF;FF;FF;FF;FF;FF;0;FD
```

[excel result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJXlv.png)

```
Sub FilterFile2()

    Dim log_path As String
    Dim log_file As String
    
    Dim objConnection As ADODB.Connection 'Object
    Dim objRecSet As ADODB.Recordset 'Object
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim ws As Variant
       
    strPath = "I:\Codici\Excel\filtra_file_testo"

    strTable = "test_2.txt"
                          
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & strPath & ";Extended Properties='Text;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'"
                 
    ' SAME PROBLEM
    'strConnection = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
    '                "Dbq=" & strPath & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;" 'HDR=NO;Persist Security Info=False"
    'https://www.exceltip.com/import-and-export-in-vba/import-data-from-a-text-file-ado-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html
                 
    ' SAME PROBLEM
    'strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    '"Data Source=" & strPath & ";Extended Properties='Text;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'"
                  
    'ADOX doesn't read the data, you still use ADODB for that.
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.Open strConnection
    
    strSql = "SELECT * " & _
    " FROM " & strTable & _
    " WHERE F3='FF'"
    '" WHERE F2='9CE78280'" 'the same problem

    Debug.Print strSql
           
    Set objRecSet = New ADODB.Recordset
    objRecSet.Open strSql, objConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    'Set objRecSet = objConnection.Execute(strSql)
    If objRecSet.State <> adStateOpen Then
        objConnection.Close
        Set objConnection = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Copy Data to Excel'
     Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ''ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset objRecSet
    ws.Cells(12, 2).CopyFromRecordset objRecSet 'write new data 'colonna 5 e 6 non corrette

    objRecSet.Close
    objConnection.Close
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi - the sample data and results you have given don't seem to correspond. Please can you provide:
Some sample data
The results you are getting using that sample data
The results you want to see using that sample data

Thanks

Comment: yes, I am sorry, I was in a hurry and I thought it was due to the length but it is not. Now I put the right input data. It is needed also Schema.ini with [test_2.txt] Format=Delimited(;) otherwise nothing works.
I am using Office 2007 on windows 10
I've add the references "Microsoft ActiceX Data Objects 2.8 Library" and "Microsoft ActiceX Data Objects Recordset 2.8 Library"